# Science fiction movie, man wandering the desert, tribble-like creature with him

Tags: story-identification, movie

I honestly wish I could remember more. I saw the movie on TV, which was either cable (a sci-fi channel) or just broadcast (in the Houston, TX, area, if that helps) in the late 90s or very early 2000s. It felt like an 80s-90s movie; the main character was a guy in black leather. What stands out is that he had either a sidekick or was being followed by a furball, like a tumbleweed but fur, and I THINK it talked to him, psychically or otherwise. Think of a bigger Tribble.

Movies it wasn't (I'm sure it's not):

- Any of the *Mad Max* films
- *A Boy and His Dog*
- *Zardoz* (although that came on the same channel, if it helps)